# NetBeans project load error "Unsupported class file major version 60"

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

i'm new on "Java world" and i'm trying to load an existing project developed with NetBeans unsuceffuly.
I'm using `netbeans 12`, `Java JDK 13` and `Gradle 6.8.3`.
This is the error that i get:

```
*"Unsupported class file major version 60<br/>BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60<br/>Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\groovy\modules\gradle\nb-tooling.gradle' (C:\Users\mv\.gradle\caches\6.8.3\scripts\dbqolnuhfyiooojod4m7h9m8m).<br/>Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\groovy\modules\gradle\nb-tooling.gradle' (C:\Users\mv\.gradle\caches\6.8.3\scripts\dbqolnuhfyiooojod4m7h9m8m).<br/>Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\mv\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.8.3-bin\7ykxq50lst7lb7wx1nijpicxn\gradle-6.8.3'."*
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: this means that you compiled the code with a newer version of Java then the one of the JRE you're trying to run it on. Update your system and run it on a newer version, or re-compile it with an older version.

Comment: My main idea would be to search StackOverflow for answers before asking.  This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: For the record, version 60 corresponds to Java 16.  So some of the code you are trying to run was compiled on / for Java 16 ... not Java 13.

Comment: And for the record, Gradle 6.8.3 won't handle Java 16.  You need Gradle 7.0; see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13629

Comment: thaks for the helps, i don't know why but even if i setted on Netbeans to use JDK 13 it was using the 16. After i've unistalled the jdk 16, the project was loaded correctly